# DBGrid Filter, Delphi.

Tags: sql, delphi, filter, delphi-7, advantage-database-server

I've recently delved into the world of Delphi, for my current mini project I'm obtaining data via an SQL query and then using the filter property to display exactly what I want.

I discovered the filter by mistake and now prefer it instead of making multiple connections or calls to the database.  For example, I'm returning a person object that may own many cars, the app has a check box and depending which one is selected it will update the filter to display only he cars that are blue or pink or whatever.

As far as I understand it, the filter works like a where clause but on the Dataset that is returned from the initial query.  So, my question is:  Is it faster to use the filter property when working with a small dataset in this manner and I am completely wrong in thinking that Dataset is returned, stored and then the filter is applied to that as opposed to constantly being updated?

I've looked online, the resources do lead me to believe that it is more efficient but I'm still unsure.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filter on a dataset does indeed work (or at least behave) like a `WHERE` clause, and in some cases can be very fast.

The issues with depending on filters are:

1. Increased network traffic. You're moving considerably more data from the server to the client that isn't needed, because you're just filtering it out anyway.
2. Filters are applied to the data row-by-row. A `WHERE` clause can be optimized by the server to be all (or at least partially) based on existing indexes, whereas the client does not have those indexes available.
3. Increased memory and CPU use on the client to maintain data it isn't using in memory and to process the rows for filtering.
4. Data updated by other users or processes is not visible to the client app, as you're now working with all of the data in local memory and not refreshing from the server.

IMO, using a filter on all but a trivial dataset isn't a good option, and if the amount of data is that small you can move the entire dataset into a `TClientDataSet` and keep it in memory yourself anyway. Like every other optimization being considered, the proper answer depends on the needs of your application and the actual data in question, and should be benchmarked using that criteria to determine what is actually the better solution.

Comment: thank you for a comprehensive answer.  I was hoping that it would have more pros than cons but form your answer it would appear that's not the case which is a shame because of all the effort that has so far gone into the application.  

I'll look ingot he TClientDataSet as I don't like the idea of making a call to the DB each time the user changes a tick box, that being said, I had thought that the result of that initial query was stored someplace and the filter was then applied to that dataset only, avoiding the unnecessary overhead.

Comment: The result of the initial query *is* stored somewhere - in memory on your local machine. Setting a filter then *iterates* the rows in memory to decide whether or not each row meets the filter criteria.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood.  So, there would be less overhead on the DB in using a filter for a dataset that was quite small?  I'm expecting a mac of 20 rows or so per instance.  If I clean up properly each time the form is closed then it should...be quicker

Comment: If you're only dealing with 20 rows, a filter should work perfectly well as long as other users aren't changing the content of those 20 rows. That's a negligible (trivial) amount of data, and a filter should be very quick for that small a dataset.

Comment: No, only one user may access the details of that user at any given time so in theory it shouldn't be updated or changed in any way whilst it's open.  I'm glad the work hasn't been wasted :)  Would you still suggest a TCleintDataSet?

Comment: FWIW, you might look into the DevExpress ExpressGrid. They use an in-memory table and give you the ability to set up a bazillion different kinds of filters that let users easily view different sets of data. BTW, I've seen these used in situations where there are literally HUNDREDS of records with DOZENS of fields per record. They are incredibly fast. TMS also has some pretty snazzy grids with filters that you could check out. The point is, TClientDataSet is simply an in-memory table. DevEx and TMS both have their own that work tightly with their solutions. You could also use kbmMemTable.

Comment: That depends. What are you doing other than filtering the data for display? If you're modifying the data, or you need to sort it in various ways without requerying the server, a `TClientDataSet` (CDS for short) works well. You can create in-memory indices for sorting, filter the data, maintain a change log that can be applied back to the server's rows, nest other tables for lookups, and various other types of thing. They also make great tables for collecting user input, you can attach data-aware controls (DBEdit/DBGrid/DBText, add validations, and so forth.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: DevEx's ExpressGrid is a very expensive product that has no apparent applicability to the question asked here. It's vast overkill for a question asking if a filter on a dataset would work to "display only the cars that are blue". TClientDataSet and the standard TDBGrid work fine for the use described here.

Comment: I'm not going to presume to make assumptions about the OP's situation. It might, in fact, be a perfect solution to their needs. My point is that it does exactly what he's asking about, and the performance I've observed in actual production apps is nothing short of amazing. They can download the demo and try it out to see what the performance is like. The OP obviously has a concern about performance when it comes to filtering, and the ExpressGrid is one huge honker of a mother-filter component! If he's happy with its performance, he'll be happy with his own simple approach.

Comment: Both, thank you so much for taking the time to answer and share your knowledge, I had no idea about the ClientDataSet it the ExpressGrid prior to this post being asked.  The filter is only for visual purposes in a  read only situation.  I think, based on what has been mentioned that the Expressgrid may be a slight overkill for this purpose but it's definitely something I can now consider for future apps, in addition to that I can experiment with the clientdset which sounds very interesting as well.  Sincere thanks again, this was exactly the type of answer I was looking for but couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

Two different animals. You're asking if it's less overhead to repeatedly query a database or do the filtering exclusively on the client side.

If your app and db are both running on the same machine, then it's probably a toss-up.

But if you're running this in a client-server, n-tier, or partitioned mobile application, and this is a common operation, then I'd say you're probably better off cacheing a larger set of results made in a single query on the client side and using filters to allow the users to see different views of the results. That reduces the bandwidth to the host and the users enjoy faster response times.

(It's a pet peeve of mine to be searching for cars or apartments or real estate and I check or un-check a box to change the view, and I have to wait 5-10 seconds for the app to reply.)

That said, you might also want to consider the overall size of the data, it's temporality, how often it's updated, and see if it's worthwhile loading down significant chunks to the client and localize even more of the specialized views. Pull down whole records and cache them locally to offer users faster response times. And minimize reloading of cached records whenever possible.

A lot of times, the actual data is fairly small on a per-record basis. But when you add-in the media stuff, it explodes. People often don't think about that, considering only the aggregate size of each "record" including the media blobs. If the DB designer was smart, the media isn't even being stored in the DB, but elsewhere, and accessible via URLs.

Comment: It's currently in dev so both are on the local machine but when released it will be client-server.  I also have that pet peeve, it's irritating as hell.  :) 
It is quite a small dataset that the qry is returning, perhaps a max of 20 rows person.  the data contained within is also relatively small and mainly consists of ints or chars.

Comment: Honestly, the larger the dataset, the bigger the improvement you're going to see by caching data locally. Remote queries are far more expensive than local filtering as long as the data is fairly static and you don't have to worry about contention -- as in real-time updates on things like accounting data, time-sensitive transactions (eg., stock trades) and similar stuff.